# How to use Lambda with S3 events in AWS

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I came across this question in my AWS study:

> A user is designing a new service that receives location updates from
>   3600 rental cars every second. The cars location needs to be uploaded
>   to an Amazon S3 bucket. Each location must also be checked for
>   distance from the original rental location. Which services will
>   process the updates and automatically scale?

```
Options:
A.  Amazon EC2 and Amazon EBS
B.  Amazon Kinesis Firehose and Amazon S3
C.  Amazon ECS and Amazon RDS
D.  Amazon S3 events and AWS Lambda
```

My question is how can Option D be used as the solution? or should I use Firehose to ingest (capture and transform) data into S3?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the catch here is 

> Each location must also be checked for distance from the original rental location.

The code running in Lambda would need to process that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would choose Option B

a.)This provides a service to ingest data directly to S3

b.) Firehose would have Lambda transformation which can compute the distance from the original location and that can be stored in S3